# Solaris11: recover file from repository

Tags: solaris

I have edited bad an important file of solaris11,i want to recover from pkg repository.
How to do that?
Suppose i have delete /usr/bin/vim,how to recover only this file from repository?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36802/gijmp.html) documentation.

Pkg revert is the solution

For example

```
pkg revert /usr/bin/vi
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of how the command is used in your answer?

Comment: simply use pkg revert /yourdir/yourfile